# Compiling .asm and .c files gives "i386 incompatibility" problem when trying to link objective files

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm, ld

I'm trying to accomplish an exercise, which goal is to print a message without C standard library, using own nasm code instead. I've successfully compiled two .asm and one .c file with following commands

```
nasm -f elf start.asm
nasm -f elf calls.asm
gcc -Wall -c greet.c
```

all good, but when I try to link all of the objective files with

```
ld start.o calls.o greet.o -o greet
```

it says

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file 'start.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: i386 architecture of input file 'calls.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

I've tried using following command instead

```
ld -m elf_i386 start.o calls.o greet.o -o greet
```

but no good

```
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'greet.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Please help. I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 (Virtual Machine), NASM ver. 2.14.02, GCC ver. 9.2.1 20191008.

Comment: You need to compile `greet.c` with `-m32`.

Comment: What's the output of `file *.o` in that directory?

Comment: @fuz, thank you! That worked!

Comment: @AndrewHenle, it was ELF 64-bit relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped. After I added -m32 it changed to ELF 32-bit

Comment: @ftl87 Note that if you link through `ld` instead of `gcc`, you must not call any libc functions and the entry point of your program is `_start` instead of `main`.

Comment: @fuz, got it, thank you!